# How to pass method (class) into ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have class called `Query` which contains a function which calls data using SQL query.

```
        public static UserDetails[] BindDatatable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["###"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 3 Deal, [property], [event] from [dbo].[Database_CRE_Events]", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                    user.Deal = dtrow["Deal"].ToString();
                    user.LoanProperty = dtrow["property"].ToString();
                    user.Events = dtrow["event"].ToString();
                    details.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

I would like to know how I can pass this query into my WebAPI controller?  Is this possible, as I could not find much examples online to further guide me with this build.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    private cdwEntities db = new cdwEntities();

    private Query respository;

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage getData()
    {
       // Not sure how to pass method from Query class here?         
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: So you want to pass the raw sql string to your BindDataTables method? Or do you want to call the BindDataTables method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why is the method in `static`?

```
public static UserDetails[] BindDatatable()
```

so if its static then you must consume it like this.

```
var result = Query.BindDatatable();
```

But if that was a mistake then you must consume it like this, your current implementation is already correct, all you have to do is **remove** the `static` modifier and then call it on the `respository` instance.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getData()
{
   var result = repository.BindDatatable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple because your method is static. A call to static method uses the following syntax

```
Classname.Methodname();
```

In your case `Query.BindDatatable();`

Your code can be modified as follows

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    private cdwEntities db = new cdwEntities();

    private Query respository;

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage getData()
    {
       //Calling the static method in Query class
       var details = Query.BindDatatable();

       //Your code here
    }
}
```